# SQLAlchemy Association Proxy - Preventing Duplicate Entries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using an [Association Proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to set up an indirect many-to-many relationship where a `Submission` can have multiple `Role`s, and a `Role` can be associated with multiple `Submission`s. Note that I'm also using `flask-sqlalchemy`.

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Submission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'submission'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    submission_to_role = relationship("SubmissionToRole", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    roles = association_proxy('submission_to_role', 'role')


class SubmissionToRole(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'submission_to_role'

    submission_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('submission.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    submission = relationship(Submission)
    role = relationship(Role)

    def __init__(self, role):
        self.role = role
```

I need behaviour like this:

```
submission = Submission()
role_a = Role('Backend Developer')
role_b = Role('Frontend Developer')
db.session.add(submission)
db.session.add(role_a)
db.session.add(role_b)
db.session.commit()

submission.roles.append(role_a) # submission.roles length should become 1
submission.roles.append(role_b) # submission.roles length should become 2
submission.roles.append(role_a) # submission.roles length should remain 2, since I already associated role_a previously.
```

But instead, when I associate an already associated `Role`, SQLAlchemy  creates a duplicate Association Object.

---

How can I accomplish my desired behaviour? I wrote a function for `Submission` that gets around it

```
def associate_role(self, role):
        assoc_model = SubmissionToRole.query.filter(
            SubmissionToRole.submission_id == self.id
        ).filter(
            SubmissionToRole.role_id == role.id
        ).first()
        if not assoc_model:
            self.roles.append(role)
```

but want something that's cleaner and easily reusable. Is there anything native to SQLAlchemy that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) on `SubmissionToRole`, which lets you specify that while the many-to-many table will have duplicate values for both `Role` and `Submission` independently, there should never be a duplicate of *pairings* of `Role` and `Submission` values. This is known as a composite unique constraint.

```
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint


class SubmissionToRole(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'submission_to_role'

    submission_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('submission.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    submission = relationship(Submission)
    role = relationship(Role)

    def __init__(self, role):
        self.role = role

    # explicit/composite unique constraint.  'name' is optional.
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('submission', 'role', name='submission_role_uc'),
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `orm`, you can simply use sets, then the method `add` instead of `append` is available:

```
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.ext import associationproxy as ap

class Role(Base):
    id: orm.Mapped[int] = orm.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: orm.Mapped[str] = db.Column()

class Submission(Base):
    id: orm.Mapped[int] = orm.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    role_association: orm.Mapped[set["SubmissionToRole"] = orm.relationship(back_populates="submission", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    roles: ap.AssociationProxy[set["Role"]] = ap.association_proxy('role_association', 'role')


class SubmissionToRole(Base):
    submission_id: orm.Mapped[int] = orm.mapped_column(db.ForeignKey('submission.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    role_id: orm.Mapped[int] = orm.mapped_column(db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    submission: orm.Mapped["Submission"] = orm.relationship(back_populates="role_association")
    role: orm.Mapped["Role"] = orm.relationship()
```